# What does pip do with the files in doc directory

Tags: python

I'm a newbie. I downloaded a Markdown tar.gz file from pypi. I install using pip:

```
root@machine:/home/user# pip install Markdown-2.4.tar.gz 
Unpacking ./Markdown-2.4.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-dV31I7-build/setup.py) egg_info for package from file:///home/irwan/Markdown-2.4.tar.gz

Installing collected packages: Markdown
  Running setup.py install for Markdown
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/markdown_py from 644 to 755
    Converting docs/release-2.1.1.txt -> build/docs/release-2.1.1.html
    Converting docs/index.txt -> build/docs/index.html
    Converting docs/release-2.1.0.txt -> build/docs/release-2.1.0.html
    Converting docs/release-2.0.2.txt -> build/docs/release-2.0.2.html
    Converting docs/reference.txt -> build/docs/reference.html
    Converting docs/release-2.0.txt -> build/docs/release-2.0.html
    Converting docs/cli.txt -> build/docs/cli.html
    Converting docs/test_suite.txt -> build/docs/test_suite.html
    Converting docs/siteindex.txt -> build/docs/siteindex.html
    Converting docs/release-2.3.txt -> build/docs/release-2.3.html
    Converting docs/change_log.txt -> build/docs/change_log.html
    Converting docs/release-2.0.1.txt -> build/docs/release-2.0.1.html
    Converting docs/release-2.2.0.txt -> build/docs/release-2.2.0.html
    Converting docs/authors.txt -> build/docs/authors.html
```

I cannot find any of above text file and html files in the filesystem. Anyone knows where pip copies them to.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like they go to the build directory.  But, that's located somewhere in `tmp` ... (probably `/tmp/pip-dV31I7-build/build`).  And it probably gets deleted when `pip` exits.

Answer (score 0):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5125951/3227133) to a similar question states, pip doesn't handle documentation generation and installation.

However, this particular package generates documentation during build process. I don't know if there is a way to make pip not delete the temporary build directory, but you can easily build a package manually:

```
tar -xzf Markdown-2.4.tar.gz
cd Markdown-2.4/
python setup.py build
```

The generated documentation is placed into `build/docs/` directory as build report says.